# virtual environment(ubuntu) NameError: name 'mark' is not defined

Tags: python, virtualenv, nameerror

I am new to Linux. Currently I am using WSL(Ubuntu). In my virtual environment this code does not work, but on online IDE the same code works. I have installed latest version of python into my virtual environment.

```
word_one = input("Enter the first word:")  #input mark
word_two = input("Enter the second word:") #input mary

# if element

if word_one > word_two:
    print(word_two,word_one)

else:
    print(word_one,word_two)
```

to execute

```
python test.py
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    word_one = input("Enter the first word:")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mark' is not defined
```

update:
even after installing the latest version of python into my virtual environment, it was still running as python2, so whenever I do "python test.py" it was running the python script using old version. To solve this I had to use "python3 test.py" and it was working good.

Question? 
is there a way where I can make python3 as my default execution, so whenever I type 
"python test.py" it can run using latest version?

Comment: One easy way is to add `alias python=python3` in your `.bashrc`.  You can also use a symlink in `~/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

You have to update first.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6
```

Notice: Please make sure your path and Python version.

And you can switch Python version in this code.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config Python
```